# EPPlus Row.Height not working

Tags: c#, epplus

I wanted to edit the `Height` Property of a `Row` but it seems not working.

```
using(var p = new ExcelPackage(fi))
{
    var ws = p.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
    if(ws == null) return;
    var rowFrom = 22;
    foreach(var item in MyListCollection<>) 
    {
        rowFrom++;
        ws.InsertRow(rowFrom, 1);
        // .. set values n stuff .. 
        ws.Row(rowFrom).Height = 12.75;

        // Set Border Style, PatternType/BackgroundColor (is working)
    }

    ws.Calculate();
    p.Save();
}
```

After doing this, the height is still default.

Does someone know a fix or a other method to change the `Row`'s `Height` ?
The file format is `.xlsm`.

Note: Installed `EPPlus` from NuGet.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem. Even when creating an XLSM the row height is still set.

Comment: @VDWWD I added some more code if it helps.

Comment: Yes it helps. Tested your code exactly. I get a correct row height. So the problem is not in that code.

Comment: Same is with `Free Spire.XLS` to convert excel to pdf the method `LoadFromFile()` isnt working there too (gettin error while doing the same like documentation`. But what can it be ? Maybe i can try to send u the Excel file if u want. I also saved the document to `.xslx` because there are no macros in the file, which also not work.  have a header and footer in my excel, may this be the reason, that this will not work ?

Comment: Could be. Start with an empty sheet and see if it is working then. If so gradually add more content from the real xlsx and see what is causing the issue.

Comment: Perhaps try setting row height last? I know there's a few formatting functions that could overwrite and reset it to default.

Comment: @Char setting the row height at last also doesn't work (1 line above `p.Save()`)